# Array output x and y axis on grid

Tags: c++, arrays

I am trying to output my array into a 2D grid(but thats not the problem), however the range of the x and y axis will be whatever the user inputs (so for e.g. x axis can be 0-8 , or 0-10 up to the the user's preference). I mean i can only hard code it in such that the x and y axis range is fixed. Something like that:

```
char gridArray[5][5];

for( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
{
  for( int j = 0; j < 5; j++ )
  {
    gridArray[i][j] = 'O';
  }
}

for( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
{
  out << i + 1 << "  ";
  for( int j = 0; j < 5; j++ )
  {
    out << gridArray[i][j] << "  ";
  }
  out << endl;
}
```

Comment: Use a `std::vector<std::vector<char>> gridArray;` instead and allocate the necessary rows and columns at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments, you should probably use `std::vector` for dynamic arrays. E.g.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstddef>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Enter x and y size, followed by enter: ";
    std::size_t nrOfRows, nrOfCols;
    std::cin >> nrOfRows >> nrOfCols;

    // initialize dynamic array of arrays
    std::vector<std::vector<char>> data(nrOfRows,
        std::vector<char>(nrOfCols, 'O'));

    // print array
    for (std::size_t rowNr = 0; rowNr < nrOfRows; rowNr++)
    {
        std::cout << "Row " << rowNr << ": ";
        for (const auto& el : data[rowNr])
            std::cout << el << " ";
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

if i didn't misunderstand you, you need to use dynamic memory allocation so you can write code like this:

```
int x, y; //  input these varialbles in any way

char ** array = new char* [y];

for (int i = 0; i < y; i++) {
    array[i] = new char[x];
}
// your code setting and showing the array

for (int i = 0 i < y; i++) {
    delete [] array[i];
}
delete [] array;
```

(sorry I'm using a phone so formatting might be a bit off)

Comment: This is not a modern C++ approach.

Comment: @JHBonarius _`char ** gridArray = new char[y][x];`_ doesn't even compile.

Comment: now it doesn't. it's the way to go if you want to create a multidimentional array because it's essentialy what vector does. I needed a few attempts to remember this because it's not the usual way to do it. the correct way would be to create a one dimentional array and calculate current row and column from one digit because it's faster.